# How can I take all the data from the one column, and display it as a single row?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have tried group concat but i cant seem to get pass the

> SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dvd_db.f.title' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

I also do not want to disable the mode. is there any other ways i can group the data to display them in a single column?

note: i used concat inside before, as i needed to join both the first and last name to get the full name. now i only need group all the fullnames.

this is the code:

```
select f.title, f.release_year, f.description, f.rating, c.name,  
         CONCAT(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) as full_name
from film f
    join film_category fc on f.film_id = fc.film_id
    join category c on fc.category_id = c.category_id
    join film_actor fa on f.film_id = fa.film_id
    join actor a on fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
where title = "ACADEMY DINOSAUR"`
```

Tried this, which gave the only_full_group_by error

```
select f.title, f.release_year, f.description, f.rating, c.name, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name)) as full_name
from film f
    join film_category fc on f.film_id = fc.film_id
    join category c on fc.category_id = c.category_id
    join film_actor fa on f.film_id = fa.film_id
    join actor a on fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
where title = "ACADEMY DINOSAUR"`
```

Comment: You need to put all your non-aggregated fields inside the `GROUP BY` clause. Although you are missing it utterly. Add `GROUP BY f.title, f.release_year, f.description, f.rating, c.name` at the end of the second query.